# Session state blocking async ajax call from processed concurrently

Tags: asp.net, session, jquery, pagemethods

I am trying to make 6 asynchronous jQuery ajax calls to my .NET Page Method all at once on document.ready to request for different sets of data from the database and in return render as charts  to users.

Problem is that when one chart takes a long time to generate, it locks up generation of the next 5 charts, for instance, when each chart takes 1 min to generate, the user will be approx waiting for 6 mins, instead of 1 - 2 mins which i thought it will be when using async ajax calls and page method gets processed in parallel.

After reading a lot of useful posts in this forum, i found that this is because I have to read and write to session objects within the page methods, and asp.net will lock the whole request, as a result making them run sequentially.

I have seen people suggesting to set the session state to read only in @Page tag, but it will not address my problem because i need write to the session as well. I have considered moving from inProc session to sql database session, but my session object is not serializable and is used across the whole project.  I also cannot change to use Cache instead because the session contains user specific details.

Can anyone please help and point me to the right direction?  I have been spending days to investigate this page inefficiency and still haven't yet found a nice way yet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Another thing is that this is my first time to post a question in this forum, so hopefully my question is making sense :)  Best wishes and thanks again

Comment: IMHO a high dependency on Session indicates poor design in web applications. Perhaps you can explain why Session is involved at all in the generation of charts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my personal experience, switching to SQL session will NOT help this problem as all of the concurrent threads will block in SQL as the first thread in will hold an exclusive lock on one or more rows in the database.

I'm curious as to why your session object isn't serializable.  The only solution that I can think of is use a database table to store the user specific data that you are keeping in session and then only holding onto a database lock for as long as it takes you to update the user data.

You can use the ASP.NET session id or other unique cookie value as the database key.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I am looking for a way to allow me to manually lock or unlock the session object if possible.  Since the current project that i am working on is huge i want to minimize the impact as much as i can.

Comment: And because of that switching to SQL session will be my last resort if possible.  My current session object is not serializable because it contains circular reference, but please do correct me if i am not making sense, cause i didnt really dig too deep into converting the project into SQL session yet.  :)

Comment: Yes, I see.  Hopefully someone else will have a suggestion on how to do that.  Another idea is to consider using a caching block and adding a user unique ID to the cache key.

Comment: Again, SQL session won't help.  I've seen multiple requests from single users get queued in SQL server session database.  Microsoft's response was that the code was working as designed.

Comment: I did roughly tried out Caching, and it does solve the issue of the whole request locking yet i have read that cache could expire itself, it that correct?

Comment: You can specify an absolute or sliding cache expiration when you add something to The ASP.Net System.Web.Caching object.  See [Cache.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add.aspx) documentation for more details. `DateTime absoluteExpiration TimeSpan slidingExpiration` arguments control the expiration of the content.  As you already should be aware since you are currently using INPROC session that this caching solution will not work across load balanced servers as each server will have its own copy of the cached objects.

Comment: OK I shall look into this slidingExpiration and absoluteExpiration parameters.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may not be server side at all.

Browsers have a built in limit on how many concurrent HTTP requests they will make - this is part of the HTTP/1.1 spec which sugests a limit of 2.

In IE7 the limit is 2. in IE8 it is 6. But when a page loads you could easily hit 6 due to the concurrent requests for CSS, JS, images etc.

A good source of info about these limits is [BrowserScope](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network) (see Connections per Hostname column).

What about combining those 6 requests into 1 request? This will also load a little faster.

Comment: HI saille, thanks for your response. I have actually added in the following code in my web.config to increase the number of concurrent processes to 20

Comment: <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="20"/></connectionManagement><system.net>

Comment: And from fiddler and chrome i have checked that the requests are sent concurrently and also started at the same time

Comment: OK, if the requests are concurrent in Fiddler, you are dealing with server side concurrency. Just thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Yep sure thing, thanks saille, that is actually a very crucial point indeed, i was initially running into that 2 concurrency thing and keep finding out why only 2 requests go first, so thumbs up :)